# Using gpt-3 to manages a business

Tags: artificial-intelligence, business

In my company, all decisions are made by a gpt-3 algorithm. It runs the entire business, from hiring to firing to product development to marketing. (These decisions are laid out in multiple-choice options by the board and shareholders; gpt-3 selects and prioritizes them)

The business is doing well, but gpt-3 often makes decisions that are counter-intuitive or strange. For example, it might launch a new product that no one wants or it might fire all of the customer service representatives.

What can I do as a majority shareholder to make sure that gpt-3 is making good decisions for the business?

*(This question was mostly generated by gpt-3)*

Comment: AFAIK gpt-3 can generate text, it can not generate decisions. I have a strong suspicion that there are humans behind the scenes who manipulate this particular algorithm.

Comment: VTC because (a) [GPT-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPT-3) is not a decision-making algorithm, which means we have no structure to work with, (b) you appear to be asking us how to enhance a real-world algorithm that doesn't do what you describe. I'm usually happy to retract my vote, but I'm not sure asking for help modifying a real-world computer algorithm (no matter what it does) - even for a worldbuilding purpose - is within the scope of worlbuilding. That might make a good [meta] Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this question. As the majority shareholder, you have a lot of power and influence over the company, but you cannot directly control the gpt-3 algorithm.

One thing you can do is try to influence the Board and shareholders to give gpt-3 more specific instructions. For example, you could ask the Board to give gpt-3 a list of priorities for the company, or you could ask the shareholders to give gpt-3 specific instructions on what they want the company to do.

Another thing you can do is try to influence the data that gpt-3 uses to make decisions. If you can provide gpt-3 with more data that reflects the company's goals and priorities, it may be more likely to make decisions that are in line with what you want.

Ultimately, though, it is difficult to control gpt-3, and you will likely need to accept that it will sometimes make decisions that you don't agree with.

[*(This answer was entirely generated by gpt-3)*](https://beta.openai.com/playground/p/U6m6TxLHuLM4bdvNS0DpSOMl?model=text-davinci-002)

[image: gpt-3's answer]